# Apple push notification certificate when moving away from Mac

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I have push notifications working on my iOS app when deployed from our development machine (mac).  However, when I try and move it to our Windows-based production server, the notifications stop working.

Has anyone had this problem porting from Mac to Windows?